# How to get current time along with the Timezone in XCode?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I tried this :

```
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss TZD"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Current Date : %@",dateString);
```

and the result I get is Date and Time but not the Timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vaibhav you have to use time zone like this

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
```

refer this link

[Get the time and date of selected time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279177/get-the-time-and-date-of-selected-time-zone)